How to approach materialized view refreshes in cases of high concurrency?
We are refreshing a materialized view once every 3 hours or so. The query is not too complex and the view itself can be created in 2 minutes.
However, because it is a frequently used view, during peak hours the constant queries and a simultanous refresh can cause the view to refresh for 20-30-40 minutes, impacting the whole database.
How could this problem be solved?
One idea I had is instead of a refresh creating a second materialized view, assigning it a synonym and then dropping the first one. But dropping could possibly decompile various dependent objects.
Are there any other alternatives?

Did you consider refreshing the MV on commit, i.e. as soon as source data is being modified (OK, committed into the database)?

You could look into fast refresh, but in most cases your best bet is simply to tune the query. If it's atomic and spending most of its time deleting and reloading (check ASH to see if this is so) then you can replace the materialized view with a normal table and a scheduled procedure that does a surgical MERGE (one for inserts and updates, one for deletes), only modifying the rows that need it, rather than replacing 100% of the table each time.

Look at using the OUT_OF_PLACE refresh option which in effect automates the strategy you were proposing.
We create a new version of the mview (whilst leaving the old one in place for queries), and then once the refresh processing is done, the data dictionary is flipped to point at the newly refreshed segment.
Queries that were running against the old segment will typically run to completion against the old segment without error.
